# Why does cv2.addweighted() give an error that the operation is neither 'array op array', nor 'array op scalar', nor ' scalar op array'?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-3.6

This is my code for image blending but there is something wrong with the cv2.addweighted() function:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('messi.jpg')
dst= cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.5,img2,0.5,0)

cv2.imshow('dst',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    dst= cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.5,img2,0.5,0)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::arithm_op
```

What is the problem? I searched the function and I'm sure that the function is correct. I didn't understand the error!

Comment: did you check both images? print shape of both of them, they have to be of the same size to be added. And they have to be loaded correctly (maybe the path is wrong)

Comment: what if they are not the same size?

Comment: the method only accepts the same size, if not how the function knows what pixel will be added with another pixel? you have other possibilities, like resize to make them the same size, or pad with a 0 border the smaller one or crop the bigger one or a lot more possibilities.... the question is how the function will be able to tell which one you want... that is why you should do it outside what you want to do

Comment: how can i put the smaller image on the bigger?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you run this:

```
dst= cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.5,img2,0.5,0)
```

Error info:

```
error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' 
(where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), 
nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::arithm_op
```

Possible reasons:

1. One or more of the img1/img2 is `not np.ndarray`, such as `None`. Maybe you havn't read it.
2. `img1.shape` does not equal to `img2.shape`. They have different size.

---

You should check `img1.shape` and `img2.shape` before you directly do `cv2.addWeighted` if you are not sure whether they are the same size.

Or, if you want to add small image on the big one, you should use `ROI`/`mask`/`slice` op.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed in one of the comments for the question and reason 2 in the answer above, you could also try to resize one of the images to match the other and then try the **addWeighted**.

Your code would then look like the below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('messi.jpg')

# Read about the resize method parameters here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#resize
img2_resized = cv2.resize(img2, (img1.shape[1], img1.shape[0]))
dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1, 0.7, img2_resized, 0.3, 0)

cv2.imshow('dst',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

even i was getting the same error. Its because of different sizes of images,then i used ROI(Region of Image), i,e., just take a portion of the image which is same as another image size.
use this code:

part=img[0:168,0:300]

## img=is the any image among the two images, which on you want perform operation and inside[ ] size of another image.

Then you get same size images and then perform operations on them.

Answer (score 0):

the cv2.resize() function takes the (width, height) as argument, which is different from what the img.shape shows (height,width)
for example:
img1 = cv2.imread("./1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("./2.jpg")
img1.shape is (200,300) and img2.shape is (200,290)
to resize img2 into (200,300) you have to run:
img2= cv2.resize(img2, (300,200))
then you can make sure they are in the same shape

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).