# Is there something wrong with my watermark app?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, photo, watermark

```
result =cv2.addWeighted(roi, 1, logo, 0.3, 0)
```

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) /private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/pip-req-build-v0gme71y/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:650: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'arithm_op'

and this is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import os


## Editing and importing the Logo
logo = cv2.imread("logo.png")
h_logo, w_logo, _ = logo.shape

images_path = glob.glob("/Users/kylebaptist/Desktop/images/saved/*.*")

for img_path in images_path:

    #img= cv2.imread("/Users/kylebaptist/Desktop/images/type.jpg")
    img= cv2.imread(img_path)

    h_img, w_img, _ = img.shape

    center_y = int(h_img / 2)
    center_x = int(w_img / 2)
    top_y = center_y - int(h_logo /2 )
    left_x = center_x - int(w_logo /2 )
    bottom_y = top_y + h_logo
    right_x = left_x + w_logo
    #cv2.circle(img, (left_x, top_y), 10, (0,255,0), -1)
    #cv2.circle(img, (right_x, bottom_y), 10, (0,255,0), -1)

            #Region of Intrest

    roi = img[top_y: bottom_y, left_x: right_x]
    #img[top_y: bottom_y, left_x: right_x] = logo
    result =cv2.addWeighted(roi, 1, logo, 0.3, 0)
    img[top_y: bottom_y, left_x: right_x] = result
    filename = os.path.basename(img_path)
    cv2.imwrite("/Users/kylebaptist/Desktop/images/saved/watermark"+ filename, img)


#cv2.imshow("roi", roi)
#cv2.imshow("Image", img)
#cv2.imshow("Logo", logo)
#cv2.imshow("result", result)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Could you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885149/7871685) to see if it helps

Comment: hello sir :) this does not help me i understand that the images are of different sizes but when i was reffering to other samples the size and the resolution of the photo didnt matter :(

Comment: are you sure both logo and roi are the same size and also have same number of channels.  sometimes png have 4 channels due to alpha/transparency, or 1 channel if its grayscale

Comment: I’ll have a look into that thank you sir !